# How long can frozen vegetables be left at room temperature?

Tags: food-safety, vegetables

I grabbed my (raw) frozen vegetables out of the freezer to bring to work, and realized upon arriving at work that they are still on the counter at home.  I am hoping that I can cook them immediately upon returning 10 hours later and be okay.  How long can frozen vegetables be left at room temperature before becoming unsafe?